# How to "flow" tagged values in Enterprise Architect from one instance to another

Tags: enterprise-architect, xmi

My questions is about bringing a concept to reality through technical availability of EA.

I am looking for a way to connect instances at an object diagram through which I can transfer tagged values. Let me explain the background of the project.

Purpose is to first have Stereotypes for specific roles in the system, such as "Calculation", "Transmission", "Decision", "Qualification", "Abstraction" etc.

Each of these stereotypes have specific tagged values suitable for their purpose.

Then I am creating instances from these stereotypes, eg. "MotorTorque:Calculation" and "LimitedTorque:Abstraction"

Each of these instances have a common tagged value, "criticality", boolean and I want this tagged value to progress from "MotorTorque:Calculation" to "LimitedTorque:Abstraction" through an output port > some sort of flow > input port kind of way.

Questions are:

1- Is this approach technically achievable in EA? If so what would be the correct way to do it?

2- The purpose is to have this "connection" readable in XMI export of the diagram which I will be using as an input for another purpose.

I have created an MDG Technology for my project with stereotypes and tagged values, however, I am having difficulty achieving this "connection", this "flow" of values.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you looked into SysML?

Comment: What do you mean by "common TV"? Shared?

Comment: I once adopted parts of SysML to create my own MDG and that worked out well. However, SysML will likely give you some ideas. (Your last comment was not complete)

Comment: I am currently looking into SysML doing a lot of reading on how it works. As for "common TV", we want to have "attributes" for these stereotypes, however, in EA, attributes are more shape related then an aspect for a stereotype. In my case, common Tag Value would be "critical" that is both belonging to/defined for "calculation" and "transmission" instances. If these instances are connected, I want their TV to be the same, if this makes any sense.

Comment: rather than shared, I want this value to affect the value of what comes downstream of this instance.  A > B such that if A is critical, and A is connected to B, then B is also critical

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not directly achievable. However, many ways lead to Rome.

One way would be to `<<trace>>` connect those objects to a `Status` class (or what ever you like to name it) and have this carry the "shared TV".

Another way is (by far more complex) to use an add-in. You would anyway need ways to create groups which share the TV. From your current explanation I can't see what that might be. Maybe the instantiating class of those instances? If so, you make a script that propagates a TV setting from ist current to all other linked instances. I'm not sure if the add-in events fire when a TV is changes (I do have some doubts here). If needed I could look that up.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, I will be dedicating some time to trying out your suggestions and will update this post for future use of others.

Comment: Don't forget to post any advice as answer to self and not as an edit to the question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you propose is partially feasible.

There is a tagged value inheritance chain in EA, in which tagged values are inherited down the generalization chain, and from a classifier to its instances. In the GUI, inherited tagged values are shown separately from the instance's own ones, and in the API they are accessed using the Element.TaggedValuesEx property. Inherited tagged values can also be overridden.

Since the correct way to create a port (or part/property) is to make it an instance of a component, a port will inherit any tagged values from that component. So if your Calculation stereotype applies to component, ports which are instances of Calculation components will inherit the MotorTorque tagged value.

However, there is no way to "flow" tagged values from one port to another. If you want such a function, you'll have to implement it yourself with an Add-In.

Regarding XMI, first you must understand that an XMI export is based on a package, not a diagram. The XMI format itself is extensible, which means that different tool vendors create their own extensions which are typically not publicly documented. Crucially, diagram layouts are part of these non-standardized extensions. In EA's case, the image data is some sort of UU-encoded bitmap which you won't be able to extract any useful information from.

Elements' tagged values are included in an XMI export, but again, the EA extensions are not publicly documented. In other words, you can import EA:s XMI format in another program, but you will need to reverse-engineer the format. Not impossible, but it's probably better to either write your own specialized export function, or [export via CSV](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/the_model_repository/csvimportexport.html). Note, however, that CSV export cannot be automated -- there's no call for it in the API.